# Transfer file with Java

Tags: java, ssh, scp, jsch

I search make a connection between one PC and one server. This connection must be done with a Java application. So I use JSCH to make a SSH connection with SCP protocol.

I managed to establish a connection but I can not transmit a file.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Logger {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {          
        try {
            JSch.setLogger(new MyLogger());
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            Session session = jsch.getSession("*****", "***.***.***.***", 22);

            // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);

            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.connect();
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static class MyLogger implements com.jcraft.jsch.Logger {

        static java.util.Hashtable name = new java.util.Hashtable();

        static {
            name.put(new Integer(DEBUG), "DEBUG: ");
            name.put(new Integer(INFO), "INFO: ");
            name.put(new Integer(WARN), "WARN: ");
            name.put(new Integer(ERROR), "ERROR: ");
            name.put(new Integer(FATAL), "FATAL: ");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int level) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void log(int level, String message) {
            System.err.print(name.get(level));
            System.err.println(message);
        }
    }

    public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return passwd;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
            Object[] options = {"yes", "no"};
            int foo = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    str,
                    "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
            return foo == 0;
        }

        String passwd;
        JTextField passwordField = (JTextField) new JPasswordField(20);

        @Override
        public String getPassphrase() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
            Object[] ob = {passwordField};
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                passwd = passwordField.getText();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void showMessage(String message) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        }
        final GridBagConstraints gbc
                = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                        GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        private Container panel;

        @Override
        public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                String name,
                String instruction,
                String[] prompt,
                boolean[] echo) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;

            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

            JTextField[] texts = new JTextField[prompt.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]), gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                if (echo[i]) {
                    texts[i] = new JTextField(20);
                } else {
                    texts[i] = new JPasswordField(20);
                }
                panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
            }

            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,
                    destination + ": " + name,
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
                    == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                String[] response = new String[prompt.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                    response[i] = texts[i].getText();
                }
                return response;
            } else {
                return null;  // cancel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I find more examples in the siteweb of JSCH but I don't understand how work the different examples. (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html)

So, I continu my search and I also found this program :

```
channel.put(from, fileName);
```

but I think this program is used for SFTP and no SCP.

I try this method too :

```
        String command6 = "scp Source Destination";

        try {
            JSch.setLogger(new MyLogger());
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            Session session = jsch.getSession("****", "***.***.***.***", 22);

            // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);

            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command6);
            channel.connect();
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
```

But she don't work...
Help me please!

Comment: can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: yes of course, sorry. I edit my message.

Comment: just a comment, I like transfer a file.. this file is .tgz..

Comment: Jsch doesn't contain an implementation of the SCP protocol. You could implement it yourself using an exec channel. You have code that opens an exec channel, and you already found some example scp code which uses jsch. You say you can't understand the example, and you apparently haven't written any actual scp client code yet. What kind of answer are you looking for here? It's very unlikely that someone is going to write your scp client code for you.

Comment: I am looking for someone to comment or explain the example. I also want to know if the example is a good track or not. I create a channel exec but when I make a command "scp path1 path2" it does not matter .. is this command misplaced? where is she wrong?

Comment: Okay, news from my program. I try to make several commands but it does not work. The program is only the last order. So, to make more order, I found this:     String essai4 = "command1; command2; command3; "; //etc...